# Is there any way to merge two javascript together?

Tags: javascript, html

I just can't figure it out how to merge them together, or I always have to write a different one for all my popups? I tried different things but none of them worked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#trigger').click(function() {
        $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
    });
    $('#close').click(function() {
        $('#overlay').fadeOut(300);
    });
});
$('#overlay').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
        if ($('#overlay').is(':visible')) {
            $('#overlay').fadeOut(300);
        }
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#trigger2').click(function() {
        $('#overlay2').fadeIn(300);
    });
    $('#close2').click(function() {
        $('#overlay2').fadeOut(300);
    });
});
$('#overlay2').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
        if ($('#overlay2').is(':visible')) {
            $('#overlay2').fadeOut(300);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: make it a function that receives the name of the elements (or just the number) as a parameter

Comment: can you show me how to do it ? I am beginner in javascript. I couldn't find a solution in other posts either

Answer (score 0):

If you use classnames or data-* attributes it's easy.

```
<div class="overlay" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="overlay" data-id="2"></div>
```

Then JS :

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
     var number = $(this).dataset().id; 
     // also valid:
     var number = $(this).attr('data-id');
     $('.overlay[data-id="' + number + "').fadeOut();
});
```

Try something similar.